# An upper bound for truncatable primess

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

> Project Euler Problem 37: (https://projecteuler.net/problem=37)
>
> The number 3797 has an interesting property. Being prime itself, it is
>   possible to continuously remove digits from left to right, and remain
>   prime at each stage: 3797, 797, 97, and 7. Similarly we can work from
>   right to left: 3797, 379, 37, and 3.
>
> Find the sum of the only eleven primes that are both truncatable from
>   left to right and right to left.
>
> NOTE: 2, 3, 5, and 7 are not considered to be truncatable primes.

I solved by assuming 1e6 as upper bound.
These are the 11 primes I got:

23

313

373

37

317

3137

3797

53

73

739397

797

How can I prove there are no such bigger primes than 739397?

I'm attaching my code in case anyone needs it.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <chrono>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iterator>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>


using namespace std;
using namespace chrono;



namespace PrimeUtils {

    const int MAXN = 1e7;

    const int MAXS = MAXN / 3;
    bool sieve[MAXS];

    const int MAXP = MAXN / 10;
    int primes[MAXP];
    int primesCount;

    inline int getNumber(int i) {
        return (i % 2 == 0) ? (6 * (i / 2) + 5) : (6 * (i / 2) + 7);
    }

    inline int getIndex(int n) {
        return ((n - 1) % 6 == 0) ? ((n - 4) / 3) : ((n - 5) / 3);
    }

    void generatePrimes() {
        int j, k;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXS; ++i) {
            sieve[i] = true;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXS; ++i) {
            if (sieve[i]) {
                j = getNumber(i);
                if (j * j > MAXN) {
                    break;
                }
                if (j % 6 == 1) {
                    for (k = j * j; k <= MAXN; k += 6 * j) {
                        sieve[getIndex(k)] = false;
                        sieve[getIndex(k + 4 * j)] = false;
                    }
                } else if (j % 6 == 5) {
                    for (k = j * j; k <= MAXN; k += 6 * j) {
                        sieve[getIndex(k)] = false;
                        sieve[getIndex(k + 2 * j)] = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        primes[0] = 2;
        primes[1] = 3;
        primesCount = 2;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAXS; ++i) {
            if (sieve[i]) {
                primes[primesCount] = getNumber(i);
                ++primesCount;
            }
        }
        while (primes[primesCount - 1] > MAXN) {
            --primesCount;
        }
    }

}

struct Problem37 {


    static const int MXPW = 7;
    int ten[MXPW];

    auto solve() {
        ten[0] = 1;
        for (int i = 1; i < MXPW; ++i) {
            ten[i] = ten[i - 1] * 10;
        }
        PrimeUtils::generatePrimes();
        vector <int> d1 =  {2, 3, 5, 7};
        vector <int> d2 =  {3, 7, 9};
        vector <int> d3 =  {1, 3, 7, 9};
        int x, s = 0;
        for (auto e1 : d1) {
            for (auto e2 : d2) {
                x = 10 * e1 + e2;
                if (ok(x)) {
                    s += x;
                }
                for (auto e3 : d3) {
                    x = 100 * e1 + 10 * e3 + e2;
                    if (ok(x)) {
                        s += x;
                    }
                    for (auto e4 : d3) {
                        x = 1000 * e1 + 100 * e3 + 10 * e4 + e2;
                        if (ok(x)) {
                            s += x;
                        }
                        for (auto e5 : d3) {
                            x = 10000 * e1 + 1000 * e3 + 100 * e4 + 10 * e5 + e2;
                            if (ok(x)) {
                                s += x;
                            }
                            for (auto e6 : d3) {
                                x = 100000 * e1 + 10000 * e3 + 1000 * e4 + 100 * e5 + 10 * e6 + e2;
                                if (ok(x)) {
                                    s += x;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return s;
    }

    bool ok(int n) {
        int t = n, g = 0;
        if (t % 3 == 0) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!PrimeUtils::sieve[PrimeUtils::getIndex(t)]) {
            return false;
        }
        while (t > 0) {
            ++g;
            if (t % 3 == 0 && t != 3) {
                return false;
            }
            if (t > 5 && !PrimeUtils::sieve[PrimeUtils::getIndex(t)]) {
                return false;
            }
            t /= 10;
        }
        t = n;
        while (t > 0) {
            if (t % 3 == 0 && t != 3) {
                return false;
            }
            if (!PrimeUtils::sieve[PrimeUtils::getIndex(t)]) {
                return false;
            }
            t = t - (t / ten[g - 1]) * ten[g - 1];
            --g;
        }
        return true;
    }

} solver;


int main() {
    freopen("output.txt", "w+", stdout);
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    auto ans = solver.solve();
    auto end = high_resolution_clock::now();
    duration <double> diff = end - start;
    cout << setw(12) << " Answer: " << setw(10) << ans;
    cout << "\n Time taken: " << setw(9) << fixed;
    cout << setprecision(5) << diff.count() << "s\n\n";
    return 0;
}

/***********************
    Answer:     748317
 Time taken:   0.05900s
 ************************/
```

Comment: You really should not be posting a solution to a Project Euler problem.  That said, it appears that none of the solvers that commented on PE did anything better than looking up the sequence of 83 right-truncatable primes in OEIS, or guessing that the upper limit was 1,000,000. A proof would be of some interest.

Comment: I think posting solutions is fine, as the only benefit derived from solving these problems is purely private, without imposing any significant cost on others. Besides even in general in math, we do need teacher to give solution for some harder problems. We can learn from the masters.

Comment: One element of [our contest problem policy](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16774) is that questions are only considered contest questions if the contest is "time-limited", i.e. "active for a fixed, finite duration of time, with a definite start and end date". "This is to prevent indefinite lock-down of information." As far as I can see, there are no definite durations at Project Euler so this is an admissible question. Please let me know in case you disagree so that I can consider deleting my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find all the right-truncatable primes by starting with the single-digit primes ($2$, $3$, $5$ and $7$) and trying to add the digits at the right that aren't divisible by $2$ or $5$ ($1$, $3$, $7$ and $9$). In each step, the right-truncatable primes with $k$ digits form the possible prefixes for right-truncatable primes with $k+1$ digits. The process terminates when you don't find any right-truncatable primes with a given number of digits. Then you just have to test each of the finitely many right-truncatable primes for left-truncatability.

Comment: Thank you. Makes sense. I will try to write the code it when I get time.

Answer (score 0):

Its a bit late, but I just stumbled upon the problem, and would like to extend a bit on @joriki 's answer.

@joriki suggested that we should find all right-truncatable primes by appending digits to the right and stop when there are no more primes available. This process gives us an upper bound of `73939133`.

Since, our problem statement requires us find numbers which are both left as well as right truncatable primes, we can find all left truncatable as well. This however gives us a worst upper bound of `933739397`.

Both the strategies can be combined by adding digits to both left and right and checking whether both are primes or not. For example, consider our initial number be 2. We add the digit 3 to both left and right i.e 23 and 32. If both 23 and 32 are primes, then we will use both of them in the next step, else discard them. This gives us an upper bound of `913331`, which is much better.